# Retrieve plain text body from email

Tags: visual-studio, basic, exchange-server-2010

Right now I use this code to retrieve the body of an email from Exchange 2010:

```
i.Load(New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Body))
Dim strEmailBodyLines() As String = Split(i.Body.Text, vbCrLf)
```

Unfortunately I get a HTML response, but I only want plain text from the body in an array (each line). If I replace ItemSchema.Body with ItemSchema.Textbody I get an error it is support on Exchange 2013 and higher.

Can someone tell me how to get the plain text body?

Answer (score 0):

I know the C# code for the same, you may convert this to VB:

```
// Create empty mail object for holding email details
EmailMessage mail;

// Bind properties from acual email message to mail object 
mail = (EmailMessage)Item.Bind(_service, new ItemId(MessageUID));
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

// Convert the email body to plain text from HTML
PropertySet propertySets = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
{
    RequestedBodyType = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType.Text
};

mail.Load(propertySets);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this with VB code.